# Opening files from device download folder android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, android-download-manager, android-fileprovider

I'm trying to open just uploaded document file from code. I don't need to get mime type explicitly, due to I receive it from server with the link on document. But when I try to open already downloaded file with

```
val uriString = Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS+File.pathSeparator+name
            val uri = Uri.parse(uriString)
            val openAttachmentIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
            openAttachmentIntent.setDataAndType(uri, attachmentMimeType)
            openAttachmentIntent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            context.startActivity(openAttachmentIntent)
```

I receive this error:
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent

But I'm 100% sure that my device have applications to open document, and that document is stored by this path.

Comment: That is not a valid `Uri`. [Configure `FileProvider` for your app](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/content/FileProvider) and use its `getUriForFile()` method to get a valid `Uri`.

Comment: it actually works, but now I faced with another problem. May be you'll be able to give me a hand with it? When I select application to open document, it says that file does not exist or impossible to open

Comment: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question with a fresh [mcve] showing what you are using now.